# The import org.w3c.dom.Document collides with another import statement in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, jsoup

I see that , a class with same name is present in different packages with in the Application .

a class named "Document.java" is present with in

When i tried to use both of them within a class , for example as shown below

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

Error in Eclipse:-

```
The import org.w3c.dom.Document collides with another import statement
```

Is there anyway to solve this without changing the name of the classes ??

How To Solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same class from different library then at the time of initialize use whole package name for one class like below

you can do either

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
public class Demo {

org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1;
Document doc2;

}
```

doc1 is the object of jsoup library and 
doc2 is the object of w3c library

or

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Demo {

Document doc1;
org.w3c.dom.Document doc2;

}
```

doc1 is the object of w3c library and 
doc2 is the object of jsoup library

Answer (score 1):

Yes, import only one of the classes, and qualify all usages of the other class with its full name:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

...
Document doc1;             // = org.jsoup.nodes.Document
org.w3c.dom.Document doc2; // = org.w3c.dom.Document
```